# D-modules on singular varieties; forgetful functors, and t-structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules

Let $Z$ be a singular variety over the complex numbers with a closed embedding $i: Z \hookrightarrow X$ into a smooth variety $X$. One can define the derived category $\mathcal{D}(Z)$ of D-modules on $Z$ to be the full subcategory of the derived category $\mathcal{D}(X)$ of quasicoherent D-modules on $X$ consisting of complexes whose cohomology sheaves are supported on $Z$. I have two questions about this category.

**Question 1:** How does one define a forgetful functor $F$ from $\mathcal{D}(Z)$ to the derived category of quasicoherent sheaves on $Z$ that agrees with the usual one when $Z$ is smooth? To me this is not obvious since pushforward of D-modules isn't in general given by pushforward of the underlying quasicoherent sheaves.

**Question 2:** Since $!$-restriction to the open complement of $Z$ in $X$ is t-exact for the usual t-structure and $\mathcal{D}(Z)$ is its kernel, the latter category inherits a t-structure from $\mathcal{D}(X)$. Can we characterize objects in the heart of this t-structure using the forgetful functor $F$? For example, is an object $M \in \mathcal{D}(Z)$ in the heart if $F(M)$ is a quasicoherent sheaf concentrated in degree $0$?

By the [work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.2087.pdf) of Gaitsgory-Rozenblyum, the forgetful functor $F$ certainly exists. However, I'd like a more hands-on description of this using the classical definition of $\mathcal{D}(Z)$ as above. They also say that in general $F$ is not t-exact, but maybe a characterization of the heart via $F$ is still possible.